# can we build a template in flex like JSF include tag or what else?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I wanna creating a flex application. In that application left, down and right side will be same all pages but on center screen will be changed in order to click event. Is that possible? When i click button on the center screen, center screen will show another MXML (call another MXML but left, right and down side will be same). How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, there is no include tag in mxml however you can use class composition or inheritance to accomplish this goal.  Using class inheritance you would create a "base class" that contains the generic features of the left bottom and right then create extensions of the base class that fill in the "center" content (you can create a box with an id as a placeholder for the section in the layout).  Alternatively you could build the left right and bottom as separate MXML components then re-use those components in each of your "page" implementations.

Hope this helps, if not please be more specific about what failure you're encountering or provide some sample code.

Thanks,

Shaun